# I'd like to change the build file and get permission

Tags: compiler-errors, permissions, sdk, frequency, microphone

Build File error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ2H0.png)

Permission error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAKNw.png)

I'd like to change the build file and get permission.
This application is an app that measures frequency through a microphone, and I downloaded it from GitHub

I got an app from GitHub that measures frequencies and ran it on my computer
This application is not working.

Does anyone know about this problem?

Thank you.